# Bootstrap full viewport div merging into another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using 3 full viewport `div` one after another using

```
<div class="vw-100 vh-100 bg-3 white">
            
           </div>
```

where bg-3 is background image and white is color: white;

The first 2 `div` works perfect but when I resize the window in Chrome or use the `Inspect` option the 3rd div pushes itself into the second one. Please see the image attached. I am using Bootstrap 4.5. Any fix for this will be great. Thanks.

[image]

It turns into this

[image]

my index.html

```js
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
          new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
    // INJECT CSS
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
body {

    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.bg-1 {
    background-color: #bd2130;
    background-image: url(images/bg-1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;  
}


.bg-2 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    background-image: url(images/bg-2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;  
}


.bg-3 {
    background-color: #ff9c08;
    background-image: url(images/contact-orange.png);
    background-size: cover;  

}



.white {
    color: white;
}

.black {
    color: black;
}

.red {
    color: #fd7878;
}

.brown {
    color: #ca793f;
}

.blue {
    color: #00adff;
}

.button1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}

.baner-content {
  width: 100%;
    padding-top: 35vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: ;
    vertical-align: middle;
}



.paddingt50 {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.paddingt100 {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.paddingt10 {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.paddingt20 {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.paddingt20 img {  /** ADDED FOR DEMO **/
  max-width: 40px; /** ADDED FOR DEMO **/
}                  /** ADDED FOR DEMO **/

.paddingL10 {
    padding-left: 10px;

}

.ickon {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 104px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f7c552;
}

.icon-circle {

   width: 125px;
   height: 125px;
   display: inline-block;
   background: #f8f8ffad;
   border: 3px solid black;
   border-radius: 50%;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
          
  <div class="vw-100 vh-100 bg-1 white text-center">


     <div class="baner-content">
              
          <h1>                  

              <p class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "test", "test", "test "]'>
<span class="wrap"></span>
</p>
         </h1>

          <p> Need a website ? We will help you</p>
          <br>

        <a href="#"><p class=" button1 white">Place an order</p></a>
          
               
      </div>

  </div>

               
            <!--Row 2 -->
          
  <div class="vw-100 vh-100 paddingt100">

    <div class="container paddingt50">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm text-center">
          
             <div class="paddingt20">

                 <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/14/47/man-5557864_960_720.jpg">

            </div>
            <p class="paddingt20">Easy Creating websites is now as simple as drinking a cup of coffee. All it takes is a phone call to us</p>
                
        </div>
          
          
        <div class="col-sm text-center">
            
            <div class="paddingt20">

                 <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/14/47/man-5557864_960_720.jpg">

            </div>
            
            <p class="paddingt20">Affordable We make sure that it does not ruin your appetite. Super affordable budget plans and renewals</p>
            
        </div>
          
        <div class="col-sm text-center">
          
            <div class="paddingt20">
            
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/14/47/man-5557864_960_720.jpg">
            
            </div>
            
            <p class="paddingt20">Best in Class Budget friendly and fast but also rich and plenty. Awesome websites like never imagined before</p>
            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
          
  </div>
    
    <!-- Row 3 -->
          
    
   <div class="vw-100 vh-100 bg-3 white"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please share more code and make a [reproducible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Updated with index.html. Hope it is fine now. Thanks.

Comment: You have some class that are not from BS. Please share those as well

Comment: Added CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix done.

So you should replace: `vw-100` by `w-100` because otherwise it will set a scrollbar horizontal.

And then I replaced all your `vh-100` by a created class `min-vh-100` to be sure that height stays fixed:

```
.min-vh-100{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

### DEMO:

```js
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
          new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
    // INJECT CSS
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
body {

    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.bg-1 {
    background-color: #bd2130;
    background-image: url(images/bg-1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;  
}


.bg-2 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    background-image: url(images/bg-2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;  
}


.bg-3 {
    background-color: #ff9c08;
    background-image: url(images/contact-orange.png);
    background-size: cover;  

}



.white {
    color: white;
}

.black {
    color: black;
}

.red {
    color: #fd7878;
}

.brown {
    color: #ca793f;
}

.blue {
    color: #00adff;
}

.button1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}

.baner-content {
  width: 100%;
    padding-top: 35vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: ;
    vertical-align: middle;
}



.paddingt50 {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.paddingt100 {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.paddingt10 {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.paddingt20 {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.paddingt20 img {  /** ADDED FOR DEMO **/
  max-width: 40px; /** ADDED FOR DEMO **/
}                  /** ADDED FOR DEMO **/

.paddingL10 {
    padding-left: 10px;

}

.ickon {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 104px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f7c552;
}

.icon-circle {

   width: 125px;
   height: 125px;
   display: inline-block;
   background: #f8f8ffad;
   border: 3px solid black;
   border-radius: 50%;

}

.min-vh-100{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
          
  <div class="w-100 min-vh-100 bg-1 white text-center">


     <div class="baner-content">
              
          <h1>                  

              <p class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "test", "test", "test "]'>
<span class="wrap"></span>
</p>
         </h1>

          <p> Need a website ? We will help you</p>
          <br>

        <a href="#"><p class=" button1 white">Place an order</p></a>
          
               
      </div>

  </div>

               
            <!--Row 2 -->
          
  <div class="w-100 min-vh-100 paddingt100">

    <div class="container paddingt50">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm text-center">
          
             <div class="paddingt20">

                 <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/14/47/man-5557864_960_720.jpg">

            </div>
            <p class="paddingt20">Easy Creating websites is now as simple as drinking a cup of coffee. All it takes is a phone call to us</p>
                
        </div>
          
          
        <div class="col-sm text-center">
            
            <div class="paddingt20">

                 <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/14/47/man-5557864_960_720.jpg">

            </div>
            
            <p class="paddingt20">Affordable We make sure that it does not ruin your appetite. Super affordable budget plans and renewals</p>
            
        </div>
          
        <div class="col-sm text-center">
          
            <div class="paddingt20">
            
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/14/47/man-5557864_960_720.jpg">
            
            </div>
            
            <p class="paddingt20">Best in Class Budget friendly and fast but also rich and plenty. Awesome websites like never imagined before</p>
            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
          
  </div>
    
    <!-- Row 3 -->
          
    
   <div class="w-100 min-vh-100 bg-3 white"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Almost everything is perfect. In the second row, the icon and text is small after modification. A bit too much white space. Just saying. I can live with that. But if you have any suggestions on the same, I will happy to listen. Thanks.

Comment: For the icon, I was adding css just for demo as mentionned in css: `.paddingt20 img {  /** ADDED FOR DEMO **/
  max-width: 40px; /** ADDED FOR DEMO **/
} ` So you should not take this